# Not selecting the Model to add an Armature

Tags: armature

[image]I have done a Lot of work to a sphere to model a Horse but now it will not select the models outline in order to add an Armature ? how do I correct this ?
When I select the horse in object mode only a few vector outlines turn orange but not the complete horse ?

Comment: You might have disabled selection in the Outliner. re-click the cursor symbol in the Outliner so it's not greyed out. You could also right click the object name and just select from the Outliner

Comment: Thanks but tha didnt work its still not showing the whole model as selected

Comment: If you upload your file here, some one can take a look. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: Could you share the solution? You can answer your own question so others can learn too.